# How to set up a web service to talk to my Windows Phone app?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

Hi and thanks for looking. Is there a way I can take in parameters from the user in my Windows Phone app, and use something like SOAP to talk to a web service and have it return an xml file? How can I host that web service for the minimum possible cost and hassle? If you could even point me to a link/tutorial, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using a number of technologies. You can use WCF for example.

There's two things for you to look at.

First is implementing the service. Here's a quick walkthrough for that - refer the first screencast.

[WCF Screencasts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-screencasts.aspx)

Second is referencing the service from your WP7 app. Here's a quick walkthrough for that. Scroll right to his first tutorial.

[AfricanGeek Silverlight 3 Video Tutorials](http://www.africangeek.com/)

For hosting you can look at any of the many shared web service hosting providers.